# Casting return type

Tags: c++

Does casting a variable to another type return a temporary copy of that variable? if so then why can't you reference the temporary variable to a function.

```
void func(int &i) //error converting parameter 1 from int to int&
{
}

int main()
{
    double d = 6.8;
    func(int(d));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes casting returns an rvalue (temporary value), but a *mutable* reference needs an lvalue.

Try this instead:

```
int main() {
   double d = 6.8;
   {
      int v = d;
      func(v);
      d = v; // if the change needs to be reflected back to d.
      // note that, even if `func` doesn't change `v`, 
      // `d` will always be truncated to 6.
   }
}
```

If `func` is not going to modify `i`, the input argument should be a *const* reference, which *can* accept an rvalue.

```
void func(const int& i);
```

(but for primitives `func(int i)` is going to be more efficient.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do `int(d)` inside the call to `func`, it creates a temporary object. You can't bind a reference to temporary. At least, not until C++0x comes and we get rvalue references (some compilers support them already, but the implementations may not be totally solid). You need to have an `int` variable defined to store the converted value, then pass that to the function.